# Is it possible to format in-text citations with author title and date in markdown/rmarkdown with CSL

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, bibtex, csl

I am trying to write a syllabus in Rmarkdown. I would like to be able to use my bibtex file and write citations in text and then knit them to html or pdf. So for instance, I would like to be able to write:

```
For week 1 please read:

+ [@author2005] Chapter 2
```

And have as output

- Arthur A. Author, *Book Title*, University Press, 2005, Chapter 2

or something roughly similar that is a long citation appearing in-text.

At the moment, I only find .csl files that either will render this as:

- (Author 2005) Chapter 2

or some other varient of author-year in-text citation, or else .csl files that render it as

- .<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Arthur A. Author, *Book Title*, University Press, 2005, Chapter 2

Is it possible to create a .csl style that produces verbose in text citations? I have been wrestling with the [csl visualizer](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) without success. If not, is there another way to tackle citations in markdown/Rmarkdown that allows more control  over the formatting of in-text citations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's absolutely possible, yes. The quickest way to do so would be to use an existing CSL style that produces note citations in the desired format and then convert it to an in-text style, which involves changing only one thing:

**Option 1**
In the style code, change `class="note"` to `class="in-text"` in the 2nd line of the style, i.e. the one that starts with `<style`

**Option 2**
Make the analog change in the visual editor under "Global Formatting Options"
[image: Screenshot from CSL visual editor]

Comment: Yes! Took me forever to find this answer!